# Unable to response headers from a jquery getJson call besides content-type and cache-control

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, ember-data

I'm doing a getJson call with jquery like this

```
jQuery.getJSON("api.url.com/resource", function(result, status, hxr) {
  console.log(hxr.getAllResponseHeaders());
  console.log(hxr.getResponseHeader('link'));
});
```

I'm only getting for hxr.getAllResponseHeaders()

```
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
cache-control: public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
```

hxr.getResponseHeader('link') is showing null,

What am I doing wrong to get the other response headers
This are all the headers that I'm getting for the request

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
cache-control:public, max-age=60, s-maxage=60
connection:close
content-length:8426
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 03 Mar 2014 23:38:22 GMT
etag:"c1b72eda189b91dd6ea837bd5e83c02a"
link:<http://api.url.com:80/v1/df?page=1>;rel="first">
Set-Cookie:connect.sid=s%3AG0eH5GaXlPq5Dc7onmNY3hGF.V%2Brv9d8DFjXXeI%2F5v9rATeTp%2FUcCxyPWScCDPiINJgY; Path=/; HttpOnly
status:200
```

Aditional Notes:

1. This is a cross-domain call
2. I'm using  jquery 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access header information in cross domain calls.